# Split OR conditions into full cases

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a list of inequalities with AND/OR conditions (A,B,C,D are all inequalities):

```
l = {A && (B || C || D)}   (This is simplified, in reality it will be far more complicated as shown below.)
```

What I want to like the following:

```
l = {A && B, A && C, A && D}
```

In other words, I want to remove all OR conditions to make it a list of conditions for all possible cases.

For your reference, the following is a real example I actually want to change using the above process. I just want to remove all OR conditions to make this expression more readable. Therefore, I would like to split the following into many different cases.

```
 (x + p δ > 
    y && (((p (-1 + v) + f v - x + y - v y)/(f v) < ρ < (
        v (f - x) + p (-1 + v + δ - v δ))/(f v) && 
       v + δ != 1) || (v + δ < 
        1 && ((v (f - x) + p (-1 + v + δ - v δ))/(
          f v) < ρ < (v (f - y) + p (-1 + v + δ))/(f v) ||
          p + x + v y + f v (-1 + ρ) < 
          p v + y)) || (v + δ > 
        1 && ((v (f - x) + p (-1 + v + δ - v δ))/(
          f v) < ρ < (
          f v δ - x (-1 + v + δ) + 
           y (-1 + v + δ - v δ))/(f v δ) || 
         p + x + v y + f v (-1 + ρ) < p v + y)))) || (x + 
     p δ < y && 
   y + x (-1 + δ) + (-1 + v) y δ + 
     f v δ ρ < (f + p) v δ && v + δ != 1)
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: `Apply[List, LogicalExpand[a && (b||c||d)]]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to make use of transposition in the general sense, and [`Thread`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Thread.html) just does it:

```
Sequence @@@ Thread[#, Or] & /@ l
```

> ```
> {A && B, A && C, A && D}
> ```